# NoClassDefFoundError with jar file in applet

Tags: java, applet, classpath, noclassdeffounderror, jakarta-mail

I've been struggling with this error for hours!  I've read some posts on StackOverflow and elsewhere, but, I can't seem to figure this out.  My applet code works fine in Eclipse.  I exported a jar file and loaded it to my web server.  When I try to execute it, I get the above error.  I've tried updating the manifest with a 'Classpath' statement, but, it does not appear to work.  I'm probably overlooking something.  Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: Not for an applet... WEB-INF/lib is for *server-side* code.

Comment: I'm sure the error tells you *which* class can't be found. That's vital information.

Comment: @rrirower are you using tomcat?

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, my bad. Excuse me.

Comment: I would start with finding out *all* the libraries which were available to the project in eclipse and compare it with the ones available to the project when it's run outside.

Comment: You should look at .classpath or `Java Build Path -> Library` view of the project to find out its dependencies.

Comment: What is the HTML used to launch the applet?  What is the structure (paths) to the resources on the server?  What class is not found? This is important information for debugging applets.  Try opening it with [Appleteer](http://pscode.org/appleteer/), which does more checks and produces more detailed output.  BTW - Why an applet rather than a frame launched using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)?  They are easier to maintain than applets.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the feedback.  The class in question is java.mail.  I'm using a hosting service (JustHost).  Will I be able to make the changes on their system some of you have suggested?  Also, I'm using Oracle's new deployment technology for applets.  It ends up calling a [javascript function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html) to deploy the applet and set some attributes.

Comment: Also, I should add, I looked at the exported jar file and it appeared to have all of the dependent jars it needed.  I tried loading the mail.jar file to the root with my jar and that did not work.

Comment: I was able to get a little further with this.  I updated the html script code to include the missing jar(s) and I no longer have an error for that.  However, I'm now getting a 'ClassNotFoundException' for my main class which lives within the jar.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

modify `common.loader` property in the `catalina.properties` file in the tomcat 'conf' folder as shown below

```
common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar
```

Also add jar files in the tomcat 'lib' folder. After doing above you must restart tomcat